# new vs. null for resetting/declaring nullable value types

Tags: c#, nullable

There are many examples online of how to use nullable value types in C#.  I also notice that there seems to be different approaches of how to initially declare the value, how to reset it, and how it use it when coalescing (relating to assigning a 'default/new' value):

Taking the following examples gathered from various online sources ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B1tcgz)):

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Initialize with null vs new");
int? b = null;
Console.WriteLine(b.HasValue);

int? c = new int?();
Console.WriteLine(c.HasValue);

Console.WriteLine("Reset as null vs new");
int? d = 123;
d = null;
Console.WriteLine(d.HasValue);

int? e = 123;
e = new int?();
Console.WriteLine(e.HasValue);

Console.WriteLine("Coalesce as null with cast vs new");
int? f = ("foo" == "bar") ? 123 : (int?)null;
Console.WriteLine(f.HasValue);

int? g = ("foo" == "bar") ? 123 : new int?();
Console.WriteLine(g.HasValue);
```

All function without issues, but I'm keen to know if there is a technical difference with either approach?  Particularly, is anything different happening under the hood that makes any approach particularly suitable/unsuitable?

Comment: It is just coding style I think. In my case, use `null` for really want to pass a `null`. And use `default` to clear the field or means nothing such like `out` parameters.

Comment: While valid, I've never personally used `new int?()` nor have I seen it used in the wild. I would probably do a double-take whereas with `null` it's obvious what's going on. I personally wouldn't use `default` for the same reason (at least with nullable types). If you mean `null` then use `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will translate all three of the following variants to the exact same IL:

- `null`
- `default`
- `new T?()`

There's no allocation, no extra memory. The runtime and the compiler treat nullable value types specially.

We can see that by using the following program and looking at the translated c# code and the IL (note `Console.WriteLine` is used to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize away the values):

```
public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int? j = A;
        Console.WriteLine(j);
        j = B;
        Console.WriteLine(j);
        j = C;
        Console.WriteLine(j);
        j = D;
        Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
    public static int? A => 3;
    public static int? B => null;
    public static int? C => default;
    public static int? D => new int?();
}
```

This is translated to the following:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static Nullable<int> A
    {
        get { return 3; } 
    }
    public static Nullable<int> B
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
    public static Nullable<int> C
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
    public static Nullable<int> D
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Nullable<int> a = A;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        a = B;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        a = C;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        a = D;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Now granted this is a *decompiled* program, but if you look at the IL you will see that the compiler returns the same value for each of `B`, `C`, and `D` (only pasting here the IL for `B` to preserve space but see the SharpLab link below):

```
method public hidebysig specialname static 
        valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32> get_B () cil managed 
    {
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
        )
        IL_0000: ldloca.s 0
        IL_0002: initobj valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
        IL_0008: ldloc.0
        IL_0009: ret
    }
```

If you can't see it or don't know IL, the interesting part is:

```
initobj valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
```

This default initializes the struct. The compiler and the runtime both have special handling of nullable types. The *default initialized** struct is how `Nullable<>` represents the `null` value.

See this [SharpLab demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAoPABhLwGYACAbxJqZr13sec4EsA7GAfhoArGgF4aAQQDcHTk2z4AnAAohAShnE5zEeIBCm7fKWqNsubpoBhQ0YUr1t7ZYAiTufdPuAvuey0FADYaXgFJMQA+Gip3fxZ8YNDBPUiaHgBXABtMmT8AhJC+QStUlDgAMwgsmFy8+MSimhdUnjgAd0KBZTNicxJvIA===).**

Now what if we elided the properties and just kept assigning `null`, etc.?

```
public static void Main() {
    int? j = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    j = null;
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    j = default;
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    j = new int?();
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}
```

The compiler just inserts a `null` reference "cast" to the struct type***.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Nullable<int> num = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(num);
    Console.WriteLine((Nullable<int>)null);
    Console.WriteLine((Nullable<int>)null);
    Console.WriteLine((Nullable<int>)null);
}
```

See this [SharpLab demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAoPABhLwGYACAbxJqZr13sec4EsA7GAfhoArGgF4aVANwdOTbPgCcACiEBKacVnMR4ngFcANgY1a5ilepmydNFHABmEQzBOn5yta602ecAO40vAJKlppu5p5WAL5WJFFAA).

I also wanted to call out that calling `new T?()` does not allocate like one of the other answers suggests. `Nullable<>` is in fact a value-type. As you see above `new int?()`  default initializes, so no allocation.

In short they are all the same. It comes down to personal preference. Personally I belive the using `null` is the best and clearest option and I think you'd be hard pressed to find someone with a different opinion. I would definitely do a double-take over `new T?` and possibly over `default` depending on the context. Simply put: you *mean* `null`, so use `null`

* Default initialization does not set the `HasValue` or `Value` properties, leaving them as `false` and `default` respectively, giving us the `null` representation

** Don't be fooled by the `box` instructions if you look at the IL for the `Main` methods above. We are calling an overload of `Console.Writeline` which accepts an `object` thus forcing the boxing of the value type.

***  As we all know structs cannot actually be `null`; this likewise demonstrates that there *is* special handling by the runtime and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't use null it's a bit less clear on how to check for "no value". Checking something like `if b == null` is clearer and easier as most people use that check to see if there's a value or not. It could create bugs where the user expects a null variable but after `new` it won't be.
2. Calling `new` will not allocate memory since this is a value type. It will always take the size of int + size of bool (the bool is there to let us know if a value was assigned or not using `hasValue`)

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I thought the whole purpose of nullable value types though was that null checks were made simple and clear with `b.HasValue` rather than `b == null`?

Comment: @EvilDr It is also a style. BTW, the `HasValue` is more faster because `==` needs additional unboxing or downcast such like `object.Equals()`. However, the runtime should optimize that and not so much different if parameter is a `null`.

Comment: HasValue is possible as well.. It's just that people are more used to check for null and will not always check HasValue

Comment: Calling  `new` will not `allocate`. We're dealing with value types here (not to mention special handling by the runtime and compiler for nullable types)

Comment: *Calling new will not allocate* - can you please elaborate what you mean here?  If you feel @YonatanNir's answer requires more clarity can you please state why?

Comment: @EvilDr See the generated IL code in my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah since it's a value type